# In dominated convergence, are we able to relax the boundedness assumption of the approximating sequence to the boundedness of the integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let

- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $X\in\mathcal L^0(\operatorname P,E)$ and $(X^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal L^0(\operatorname P,E)$ with $$\left\|X^n-X\right\|_E\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\;\;\;\operatorname P\text{-almost surely}\tag1$$ and $$\left\|X^n\right\|_E\le\left|Y\right|\;\;\;\operatorname P\text{-almost surely}\text{ for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag2$$ for some $Y\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P)$

By Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, $X,X^n\in\mathcal L^1(\operatorname P,E)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ with $$\left\|X^n-X\right\|_{L^1(\operatorname P,\:E)}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0\tag3\;.$$

> Are we able to relax $(2)$ to $$\operatorname E\left[\left\|X^n\right\|_E\right]\le\operatorname E\left[\left|Y\right|\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag4$$ or is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, even if $E=\mathbb R$: take $X^n=n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n)}$ where $\Omega:=(0,1)$ endowed with Lebesgue measure. Then for any $Y$ with expectation $1$, (2) holds but not (3). A relaxation of (2) involves uniform integrability:
$$\tag{2'} \lim_{R\to +\infty}\sup_{n\in\mathbb N} \mathbb E\left[\left\lVert X^n\right\rVert  \mathbf 1\left\{\left\lVert X^n\right\rVert\gt R\right\}   \right]=0.$$